# D3 mixing hierarchy layouts

Tags: d3.js

I'm new in the D3 world. I already understand how to build hierarchies layouts like Trees and Circles packs, but I'm not figuring out how to mix these two types of hierarchy. The idea is to construct a tree and group some of the nodes in Circles using the Pack function of D3. Can anyone give me north to where to go. I simple image to show whats the idea:

[Tree and Circle pack Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghZQR.png)

Currently, I'm using [this](https://www.d3indepth.com/layouts/) website as guide.

Comment: The linked diagram you have shown doesn't use circle packing: the circles are not packed in the most efficient manner (neither the parents nor the children). Additionally the root would be represented differently in each. Consequently, D3's circle packing layout generator is probably not what you are looking for as it fills a different purpose. You might be looking for a method to appropriately place the tree nodes so that the minimum bounding circles of each group don't overlap and are equally sized - but additional details would be needed before going down any path.